# Is it possible to create an android map application where the map is a custom image file?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

For example, for some reason I only want a map of United States with state borders but without state names or city names. I can find such a map online(an image file), and want it to be the map in my application. But I still want the ability to get geolocation data(latitude, longitude) when the user taps somewhere on the map. Is it possible to do that? If so, where should I start? Could anyone suggest some resources?

Answer (score 1):

If you create your own tiles yes it can be done with `Tile Overlay`

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/tileoverlay

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you recommend some resources on how to create your own tiles? I'm completely new to this.